# How to use COMMENTS channel without getting a warning

Tags: warnings, antlr4

I read the answer to [Why am I getting an error when assigning tokens to a channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027175/why-am-i-getting-an-error-when-assigning-tokens-to-a-channel).
The answer is that this is not an error, but a warning.

Well that's all very well, but the Eclipse IDE, https://github.com/jknack/antlr4ide, will not generate code when this warning is present.

Is there a way to not get a warning, when using a COMMENT channel?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a way around this warning. But it seems to me the Eclipse IDE should handle this instead (it *should* generate code upon warnings).

Answer (score 0):

You could trick the compiler by defining `COMMENT` in a `tokens{}` block instead of in the `@members{}` block. This would result in a constant value getting automatically assigned to it.

If you are also using the `HIDDEN` channel, I would include something like this to be safe:

```
@members {
{
  if (HIDDEN == COMMENT) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(
      "Expected the HIDDEN and COMMENT constants to have different values.");
  }
}
}
```