# Warninig 155 when using lexical mode with antlr4

Tags: java, maven, antlr4

So I have problems with using modes in antlr4 when trying to create grammar for the following simple, subset of my real problem language:

```
  a : abc
  a : xyz
  a : abc:d
  a : someonthertext
```

The grammars are:

**Simple.g4**

```
grammar Simple;    
import SimpleL;    
prog : entry+;    
entry : head semi tail tail_ws;    
semi : SEMI;    
tail : TAIL;    
tail_ws : TAIL_WS;    
head : HEAD;
```

**SimpleL.g4**

```
lexer grammar SimpleL;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
SEMI : ':' -> pushMode(TMODE);
HEAD : 'a';
mode TMODE;
TAIL_WS:  [ \t\r\n]+ -> popMode;
TAIL:[a-z:]+ ;
```

I use the antlr4 maven plugin - 4.2 and the result of the build is :

```
[WARNING] warning(155): ... antlr4/Simple.g4:5:23: rule 'SEMI' contains a lexer command with an unrecognized constant value; lexer interpreters may produce incorrect output
```

This actually breaks the java build.

```
[ERROR] ... antlr4/SimpleLexer.java:[63,19] error: cannot find symbol
```

Eclipse gives the following error:

```
TMODE cannot be resolved to a variable
```

on this line:

```
case 0: pushMode(TMODE); break;
```

The problem seems similar to [Why am I getting an error when assigning tokens to a channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027175/why-am-i-getting-an-error-when-assigning-tokens-to-a-channel)

Answer (score 2):

Combined grammars in ANTLR 4 cannot use multi-mode lexers. When importing the `SimpleL` lexer, the `TMODE` mode is ignored.

Instead of creating a `lexer grammar` and a combined grammar (just `grammar`), you should use a `lexer grammar` and `parser grammar`.

```
parser grammar Simple;

options {
  tokenVocab = SimpleL;
}
```

Comment: Nothing to say. Works.