# How to parse optional island text in antlr4

Tags: antlr4

As continuation of my [tiny language example problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271712/warninig-155-when-using-lexical-mode-with-antlr4) I would like to ask how to parse the following text. This time just want to skip the tail rule but it is an island and is not obvious for me. Best, less hackish approach?

```
a : sss 
a : eeee:yyyy 
a :  
a : tttt:aaa
```

with the the following grammars that use lexical mode:

**SimpleL.g4**

```
lexer grammar SimpleL;    

fragment WS : [ \t\r\n]+;

SEMI : ':' -> pushMode(TMODE);
HEAD : 'a' ;
WS_DEFAULT: WS -> skip;

mode TMODE;

TAIL   :   [a-z:]+  -> popMode;
WS_TMODE : WS -> skip;
```

**Simple.g4**

```
parser grammar Simple;  

options {
  tokenVocab = SimpleL;
}

prog : entry+ EOF;

entry : head semi tail;

semi : SEMI;    
tail : TAIL;    
head : HEAD;
```

The aim is to catch the case where the tail rule is not there. However if all the white spaces are skipped the next section **a : tttt:aaa** becomes a tail and I could not distinguish the cases. The target situation is to have the following:

```
(prog (entry (head a) (semi :) (tail sss)) 
      (entry (head a) (semi :) (tail eeee:yyyy)) 
      (entry (head a) (semi :) (tail )
      (entry (head a) (semi :) (tail tttt:aaa)
 ) <EOF>)
```

What I have tried were rules in the parser:

```
 entry : (head semi head semi tail | head semi tail);
```

and

```
 entry : (head semi tail?);
```

with different ordering of the lexer rules. Tried also the **more** lexical command with no success.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Can you provide a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to accomplish, the problems you have encountered, and where you think the problem lies?

Comment: Just made the question more verbose.

Comment: If the parser enters eventual rule **head semi head** I could not get back to catch the interesting for me case **head semi**. As if the solution depends on white spaces in the parser.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you do want to have 'newline' as escape character like ';' in most programming languages. Therefore NEWLINE has to become a rule and not only a white space character.